FastAPI problema con sobre escritura de dependencia de base de datos
Estoy levantando una API utilizando FastAPI y estoy teniendo problemas con los tests, a la hora de realizar un override de la base de datos. Me doy cuenta de esto porque los registros estan siendo insertados en la base de datos productiva.
Esta es la documentación de FastAPI que estoy siguiendo.
También estoy debugueando los tests, y si bien cuando estoy dentro de la función del test puedo ver el override de la dependencia get_db, si pongo otro breakpoint dentro del get_db original, veo que se llama.
Dejo una parte del código
conftest.py
SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URL = "sqlite://"

engine = create_engine(
    SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URL,
    connect_args={"check_same_thread": False},
    poolclass=StaticPool,
)
TestingSessionLocal = sessionmaker(autocommit=False, autoflush=False, bind=engine)
Base.metadata.create_all(bind=engine)

def override_get_db():
    try:
        db = TestingSessionLocal()
        yield db
    finally:
        db.close()

app.dependency_overrides[get_db] = override_get_db

@pytest.fixture
def client():
    return TestClient(app)

test_certificate.py
def test_create_certificate(client, mocker):
    mocker.patch("src.certificate.services._get_slack_team_id", return_value="S04AC3L0ENR")
    mocker.patch("uuid.uuid4", return_value="123456")
    
    response = client.post("/certificate-manager/v1/certificates", json=create_certificate_json)
    assert response.status_code == 200
    assert response.json() == create_certificate_response

views.py
# Dependency
def get_db():
    db = SessionLocal()
    try:
        yield db
    finally:
        db.close()


@certificate_manager_router.post('/certificates', tags=tags)
@basic_decorator
async def create_new_certificate(certificate_create: CertificateCreate, db: Session = Depends(get_db)):
    logger.info("Creating new certificate in controller")
    return certificate_service.create_new_certificate(certificate_create, db) 

app.py
tags_metadata = [
    {
        "name": "Certificate Manager",
        "description": "Certificate management API",
    }
]

app = FastAPI(title=f"{_SVC} API", openapi_tags=tags_metadata,
                docs_url=f"{_PREFIX_PATH}/docs",
                openapi_url=f"{_PREFIX_PATH}/openapi.json")

# Middleware for adding request id to logs
app.add_middleware(CorrelationIdMiddleware)

app.add_middleware(
    CORSMiddleware,
    allow_origins="*",
    allow_credentials=True,
    allow_methods=["*"],
    allow_headers=["*"],
)

app.include_router(routes)

